# вопрос по индексу

Tags: mysql, innodb

Есть запрос

```sql
explain 
select *
from table advert 
where (    advert.n_category between 62 and 83 
        or advert.n_category between 85 and 87 
        or advert.n_category IN ( 92,149,151 )  ) 
  and advert.hide = 'show'
  and advert.moder = 'view'
  and on_delete = 'off'
  and blocked != 'yes'
  and end_putdate > 1636681455 
  and advert.country_adv = 3159  
  and advert.region_adv =  33   
order by sort_time DESC
```

1. Индекс стоит на advert.region_adv. Сам запрос возвращает 60 тыс записей, но, делая EXPLAIN, в колонке ROW отображается другое число записей . Почему ?
2. Также, пытаюсь комбинировать поля в индексе, например region_adv + sort_time , но ничего не меняется , или если делать индекс на поле категории n_category , то он вообще не хочет работать . Этот момент не понятен вообще

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *Сам запрос возвращает 60 тыс записей, но, делая EXPLAIN, в колонке ROW отображается другое число записей . Почему ?* Ну, наверное, потому. что отображаемое в колонке ROWS значение никакого отношения к размеру выходного набора не имеет...

Comment: *пытаюсь комбинировать поля в индексе, например region_adv + sort_time , но ничего не меняется* Пытаться строить индекс по некоему мистическому наитию бессмысленно. *если делать индекс на поле категории n_category , то он вообще не хочет работать* По умолчанию сервер считает, что WHERE IN при более чем 10 значениях дешевле фуллсканить.